# Show (mods) self-deleted questions and answers in the recent activity tab

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, moderator-tools, deleted-answers, recent-activity

As a mod, I recently had to take a look into a user who had deleted some of his own posts. In trying to see what questions he had deleted and which were recent, I had to go through his entire question list. It would be a good tool for moderators to see self-deletes on a user's recent activity tab.

Comment: Or on a separate tab.